# How to call the stored procedure function by passing parameter using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having problem calling the stored procedure using PDO. I have a PDO configuration inside a class and I have to pass a parameter i.e  user input number from myfile.php. I have uploaded my files below.

```
myfile.php

include 'database.php';
$test = new Database();
$test->query('CALL calcArea(?)');
$test->bind(':s_id', $s_id);
$rslt= $test->execute();

print_r($rslt);

database.php

<?php
    class Database{
        private $host = DB_HOST;
        private $user = DB_USER;
        private $pass = DB_PASS;
        private $dbname = DB_NAME;

        private $conn;
        private $error;
        private $stmt;

        public function __construct(){
            // Set DSN
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
            // Set options
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                );
            // Create a new PDO instanace
            try{
                $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
            }
            // Catch any errors
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function query($sql){
            $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        }

        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
            if (is_null($type)) {
                switch (true) {
                    case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                    case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                    default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `bind(':s_id', $s_id)` but you don't have `s_id` placeholder

Comment: I will get $s_id from user input. In normal select queries I pass :s_id but In call function how can I pass this value?

Comment: What about passing :s_id?

Comment: **It is not PDO you are using** but a concoction of your own. I am sure I posted this link before but it seems you did't pay any attention. Next try: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: When I start to learn about PDO ,@Your Common Sense your so called genious material didnot appear to my search list. You might be expertise in pdo and know every cons and pros. But my code I code it based on tutorial I found out. I thank you for the tutorial you provided last time as well as this time and will definately go through it as I find free time. And this is stack not John Cena fan page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for an example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL calcArea(?)");
$stmt ->execute(array($s_id));
```

OR

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL calcArea(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $s_id, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 32)
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($value);//<- result is now in $value
```